# Xcode 7.2 Documentation Always Fetched From Internet

Tags: ios, xcode

I am on Xcode 7.2 and whenever I do a search on the documentation it takes about 2 seconds to display the answer. It appears to be reading it from the Internet every time as when I disconnect from the Internet nothing happens and no new pages are loaded. The image below shows that I have the documentation downloaded. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated (I have quit Xcode, restarted, etc)

[image: screen grab from xcode prefs]

Comment: What happens when you have no internet connection?

Comment: @fragilecat I get nothing. Whatever is currently displayed in the documentation viewer remains but clicking on any other method names does not refresh anything, nor does entering anything in the search view.

Comment: Wow, this is kinda interesting. It relies on the xcdoc://?  schema and as you suggest seems to require an internet connection even if you have the documentation locally.

Comment: So you're experiencing the same thing?

Comment: Not exactly, I have some offline functionality, but search is definitely being effected by the status of my network connection.

Comment: Okay, maybe I'll just submit a bug report and use Dash for the moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same problem, finally, I solved this by those steps.

1. Download the documentation which you want in the preferences -> downloads
2. Open Finder
3. click Application in left column
4. locate the Xcode, right click, and pick show package contents
5. go to this directory, contents -> Developer -> Documentation -> DocSets
6. Here you can see five files, pick which name is same as you download documentation, for me, I choose com.apple.adc.documentation.iOS.docset, put it to trash.
7. restart Xcode, problem solved.

Maybe Xcode use above location and not prefer to ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets, I think.

Comment: That did it for me too.

Comment: FYI, after I upgrade the OS X to 10.11.3, above problem has been solved.